# Why is the div container not transparent

Tags: css

I'm wondering why the div container (background-box-2) is not transparent. In my opinion it should be transparent. If you are scrolling you should have a look at the fixed background image. What is my mistake? Thanks :)

```css
.background-box {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://images.car.bauercdn.com/pagefiles/72609/mclaren-720s-01.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.background-box-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="background-box">
</div>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  S
</p>
<div class="background-box-2">
</div>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  S
</p>
```

Comment: You have a semi-transparent white background overlaying a white background, so it's not visible. As a quick test, if you add the style `body { background: red; }` you will be able to see your background box is actually semi transparent, you've probably just positioned it incorrectly?

Comment: I am not fully sure to understand the question, are you trying to create a Parallax here ? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp

Comment: Do you mean to not have nested `<div>`?

Answer (score 0):

It is transparent, but it does not overlay anything apart from white space. Add position:absolute or such to make it overlap with other elemetns.

Comment: if you are scrolling it should overlay the background image?

Answer (score 0):

You have given background image for the first div which doesn't contain any content within it. You should take all the content inside first div, so the background image will get applied to every content within that div.

Answer (score 0):

That's a nice question, and here is some help:

1. First, you're creating a div `background-box` which contains your background image
2. Then, you create a second div `background-box-2` that holds your text.

The problem you've got is that your first div is actually **not being overlayed by the second div**!

### But, how do I fix that?

Well, you need to be sure that your first div stays fixed as the user scrolls down. You may use `position: fixed` to achieve this ([MDN - Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)).

```css
.background-box {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://images.car.bauercdn.com/pagefiles/72609/mclaren-720s-01.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
.background-box-2 {
  margin-top: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="background-box">
</div>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  S</p>
<div class="background-box-2">

</div>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  S
</p>
```

Note that we also need to set `z-index: -1` to `background-box` (so that it stay under `background-box-2`) and set a `margin-top: 1000px` to `background-box-2` to keep the page scrollable.

Hope I helped :).

---

References:

- [MDN - position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)
- [MDN - z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)
- [MDN - Box model recap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_boxes/Box_model_recap)